I can't add a character to the Unreal Engine 5.3 game
I have a project that uses SuperheroFlightAnimations animations, I wanted to add my character, make a realtime retarget. I used it as a skeleton creation for the Mesh - ActorCore accurig. But this project does not have the mannyquins_ue4 folder, which is needed for retargeting RTG and IK skeleton. I wanted to try adding this folder from another project, but after retargeting it turns out this:
https://i.sstatic.net/A23J60s8.png
(a mesh is used here for an example)
in general, any mesh that should initially be in the correct position and position (I checked in other projects, everything is fine there) is on top, and this is not the whole problem, even if you put it in the correct position, it does not react to any animations, that is, if you act as shown in the video: VIDEO
is nothing works (the video shows how to make a realtime retarget)
I also tried to make a retarget in another project with superheroflightassets and transfer all the files ik, rtg, animation blueprint and the character himself to the current project, but the situation is the same as in the screenshot.
How to solve this problem? You can tell me what's wrong or give instructions on some other way to retarget all animations and transfer them to another character.
The repository of the project in which it is not possible to replace the character: REPO
I also tried to make a retarget in another project with superheroflightassets and transfer all the files ik, rtg, animation blueprint and the character himself to the current project, but the situation is the same as in the screenshot.
How to solve this problem? You can tell me what's wrong or give instructions on some other way to retarget all animations and transfer them to another character.

An Unreal Engine 4 file is incompatible with Unreal Engine 5. Also, I can't give you a definite answer as there are many versions of UE5 including UE 5.0, 5.1.1, 5.2.0, 5.3.2, and 5.4.0. I am using UE5.3.2. can I give you and answer for that version?

@LawnHollanderLawn of course you can, i also using ue5.3.2

I see. I will need to do some research on it then
